# how to break querySnapshot on Firestore?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I need to break querysnapshot loop. Is it possible?

I tried with for loop. but the below error is coming.

How to fix this error or Is there any way to break snapshot loop?

**code**

```
  return query.get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      for(const doc of snapshot) {
        let data = doc.data()
        if (data.age == 16) {
            break;
        }
  }
```

**error**

> Type 'QuerySnapshot' must have a 'Symbol.iterator' method that returns an iterator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`docs`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot.html#docs) property of the QuerySnapshot, which returns an array of all the documents in the QuerySnapshot.

For example, with a for loop:

```
  return query.get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      const snapshotsArray = snapshot.docs;
      for (var i = 0; i < snapshotsArray.length; i++) {
        const data = snapshotsArray[i].data()
        if (data.age == 16) {
            break;
        }
      }
  }
```

or with a `for-of`:

```
  return query.get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      const snapshotsArray = snapshot.docs;
      for (const snap of snapshotsArray) {
        const data = snap.data()
        if (data.age == 16) {
            break;
        }
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) say that `QuerySnapshot<T>` is not an iterator/async iterator so you can't use it like one. Seems like the only way to iterate over it is with [forEach](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot.html#for-each) which doesn't seem to provide a way of "early breaking".