# Vue component being loaded before calling router.push()

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vue-router

I am developing an online game for 2 players using Vue js and Firestore.

**When the new game button is clicked;**

- I create a new room and save it in the database.
- I check the changes with the firestore docChanges () function. If a new room is created, I redirect the current player and the opponent to the Game.vue page.

### **My codes**

**Home.vue**

```js
import db from "@/firebase/init";
import Navbar from "@/components/Navbar";
export default {
  name: "Home",
  components: {
    Navbar
  },
  data() {
    return {
   
    };
  },

  methods: {

    newGame() {
      this.createGameRoom();
    },
    createGameRoom() {
      let gameNo = Date.now();
      db.collection("game_rooms")
        .add({
          gameNo: gameNo,
        })
        .then(() => {
          this.createGameAndOpponent();
        });
    },

    createGameAndOpponent() {
      db.collection("game_rooms").onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
          if (change.type == "added") {

           console.log("******************************")
           console.log('Current Page Name(Static):Home.vue')
           console.log('Current Page Name(Dynamic):'+this.$route.name)
           console.log("Pushing to game component")
           console.log("******************************")
            this.$router.push("/game");
          }
        });
      });
    },
  }
};
```

```html
<template>
  <div id="home">
    <Navbar />
    <div class="home container">
      <div class="card">
        <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large btn deep-purple darken-1" @click="newGame">
         New Game
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**Game.vue**

```js
export default {
  name: "Game",
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  created() {
    console.log("******************************");
    console.log("Current Page Name(Static):Game.vue");
    console.log("Current Page Name(Dynamic):" + this.$route.name);
    console.log("Game component created");
  },

  methods: {}
};
```

```html
<template>
  <div id="game">
    <router-link
      :to="{name:'Home'}"
    >Return Home Page</router-link>
  </div>
</template>
```

**Vue Router - index.js**

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Home from '../views/Home.vue'
import Game from '../views/Game.vue'
Vue.use(VueRouter)


const routes = [{
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home,

}, {
    path: '/game',
    name: 'Game',
    component: Game,

}, ]

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes
})


export default router
```

I'm checking inside the **createGameAndOpponent** function:

If there is a change in "game_rooms" or a new game has been created, find the opponent from online users and redirect both users to the game page. But there is an error during the redirection here. The page is not redirected and gives the following error.

But I get the error below

> > Uncaught (in promise)   
> >     NavigationDuplicated {_name: "NavigationDuplicated", name: "NavigationDuplicated", message: "Navigating to current location ("/game") is not allowed"

Although the current page is Home.vue, it says the current page is game.vue and says "It is not allowed to go to the '/game' page".

I did the following to learn the problem details.

- When I clicked on the "New Game" button in Home.vue, before going to the Game page, I printed the name of the current page statically and dynamically with the console.
- In the Game.vue page, when the Game.vue component was created in the **created()** method, I printed the name of the page statically and dynamically with the console.

[image]

As the picture shows, although the Active page is Home.vue **this.$route.name** shows the name of the Game page.

I do the redirection to the game.vue in **firestore docChanges() function**. The problem should be here.
But I could not solve the source of the problem.
How can I solve the problem?

**Notes:**

- Vue Version:@vue/cli 4.1.2
- I shared the [minimal project](https://github.com/hibritusta/game) as a repo on the github.
- Online minimal project:https://vue-test-game.firebaseapp.com/

Comment: Isn't it because you do `querySnapshot.docChanges().forEach()` and therefore may redirect several times? What happens if you break after the first `change.type == "added"`? You'll need to loop with another method for being able to do that, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60260237/how-to-break-querysnapshot-on-firestore/60260422#60260422

Comment: In order for the question detail to not be too long
I deleted all unnecessary codes.
If there are active players from the players in the database, I directed to the game.vue page.I am reviewing the resource you shared. @RenaudTarnec

Comment: What I meant is that you may redirect several times to `/game` in your `forEach` loop.

Comment: I examined the source you shared. I solved the problem with "Break".
But the Game is real time, so I used the "docChanges" method.
To control and steer for both users.But in this source only active users are redirecting.Is there a method to stop Foreach? @RenaudTarnec

Answer (score 0):

In my opinions, you seems like have two problems.

Can you be sure the code below only call once ? you use a **forEach**, may be `this.$router.push` be called twice. Your log show a logic the callback has been call twice.

```
        snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
      if (change.type == "added") {

       console.log("******************************")
       console.log('Current Page Name(Static):Home.vue')
       console.log('Current Page Name(Dynamic):'+this.$route.name)
       console.log("Pushing to game component")
       console.log("******************************")
        this.$router.push("/game");
      }
    });
```

if so, you may be no need forEach but a simple `for` with `return`, or use `[].some` with return true when you attempt to `break` the loop call.

Comment: I tried the method you said but it still gives the same error.

Comment: @HibritUsta break is ok. But you should also unbind event on vue component destroy.like:  beforeDestroy() { unconnectYourFireBase() }

Comment: I'm sorry. I couldn't fully understand what you said.
Can you explain or show what you mean in more detail? @iulo

Answer (score 0):

Following our comments under your question, it seems that the problems come from the fact that you redirect several times (with `this.$router.push("/game");`) in the following loop:

```
createGameAndOpponent() {
  db.collection("game_rooms").onSnapshot(snapshot => {
    snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
      if (change.type == "added") {
        //...
        this.$router.push("/game");
      }
    });
  });
}
```

You should break the loop the first time you encounter a `change.type` which equals `added`. Since [`docChanges()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot?authuser=0#doc-changes) returns an array, you can do as follows:

```
createGameAndOpponent() {
  db.collection("game_rooms").onSnapshot(snapshot => {
    for (const change of snapshot.docChanges()) {
      if (change.type == "added") {
        this.$router.push("/game");
        break;
      }
    });
  });
}
```

---

Note the following extra points:

1. Since, by doing `db.collection("game_rooms").onSnapshot` you are setting a listener, you should call this method (only once) from the vue.js `created` hook.
2. On the other hand, in the `getGameUsers()` method, since you are querying only once the Firestore database (if I am not mistaking), it is better to use the [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference?authuser=0#get) method, which queries the DB only once.

Comment: I tried the solution method you said, but it also gives an error like the question.
I published the project to better see the problem:[link](https://dortleme.firebaseapp.com/login).You can register and login with a sample user.

Comment: I just tried with a sample user and now the `console.logs` seems to be correct. I.e.    `console.log('Current Page Name(Static)...)` matches with `console.log('Current Page Name(Dynamic):...)`

Comment: looks right at the first click.But when you go back to the Homepage and click the new game button again, it will give an error.

Comment: I'm afraid it will be difficult to help your further without a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your code is quite complex and rich, and without reproducing your entire app it is nearly impossible to give more help (even from the built instance of the app that you shared above).